# Recommended CMS for CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, installation

The CiviCRM download page shows that it is available for Drupal, WP & Joomla
I came across CiviCRM via the Joomla Extensions directory, but it seems not everything is equal among the CiviCRM installs; in particular no sample data for Joomla.  I also had problems with the 4.7.6 build and not until I tried the 4.7.7 did I get anything up and running under Joomla - but the dashboard doesnt load (I'm using WAMP for a dev environment).

What is the most supported CMS from the 3x available as far as CiviCRM is concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Drupal exclusively for all our projects. Many advantages such as drush; views integration; webform_civicrm module!

CiviCRM is CMS agnostic - and the community will support all three CMS-es. Most are on Drupal and Wordpress though so to get help - that's your best bet.

Comment: also Drupal has CiviCRM Entity, https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity .  This makes CiviCRM api entities, Drupal entities,and allows integration with Entity Reference Field, Rules, and many other Drupal modules that integrate with Drupal Entities

Answer (score 2):

Agree with KarinG. I think Drupal is the best supported and most integrated of the three CMS's at the moment. Wordpress is growing rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

This related question gives a good overview of the differences between the three CMSs:

[How is CiviCRM different in Drupal, Joomla, and WordPress?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-is-civicrm-different-in-drupal-joomla-and-wordpress)