# Civi WordPress - Document Storage

Tags: wordpress

I am currently testing Civi CRM with a view to use it for an upcoming project. I am using WordPress and want to store documents on a contacts record, is this possible? I've seen there is a documents extension available and it works on the sandbox site i've used but we would be hosting with WordPress. If I go into system settings and extensions there is a documents option but it fails to install. 
Any info would be appreciated, thanks

Edit: Also could you let me know if there is much difference in terms of functionality between what you can do with Civi in WordPress compared to Drupal please :)

Comment: Hi,

You can, without any extension, already attach documents to contacts (e.g. to notes, activities) so it may be good to find out more about the use case?

Comment: Hi Rebecca, ah thanks I have seen you can upload a document in them tabs which might be relevant to a note or activity but just wondered if they could sit in their own tab like i've seen is possible and seems to offer more functionality: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.documents.git - (in WordPress) thanks

Comment: As far as I know the Documents extension is CiviCRM native, so should work on WordPress too

Comment: Hi Cirrus, here's an existing answer to your second question. Stack Exchange favours a single topic per question, hope this helps! https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-is-civicrm-different-in-drupal-joomla-and-wordpress

Comment: Try installing another extension as a cross check? If you find that other extensions also fail to install, your question may really be "How do I configure CiviCRM to install extensions under WordPress?" Either way, including as much detail as possible about what happens when you try to install the extension may help you resolve that situation. Error messages and [log messages](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#Debuggingfordevelopers-Logfiles) add a lot to the picture.